# ES6 Filter elements from an array within an array

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I currently have 2 arrays. Each array has another array named "url".

```
{
  "entities": [
    {
      "id": 0,
      "companyName": "4-County Electric Power Assn",
      "type": "E",
      "state": "MS",
      "code": "106641MS",
      "url": [
        {
          "title": "4 County Electric",
          "link": "http://www.4county.org/",
          "href": "http://www.4county.org/"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 1,
      "companyName": "ACTON WATER DISTRICT OFFICE",
      "type": "W",
      "state": "MA",
      "code": "W1771MA",
      "url": [
        {
          "title": "Home — Acton Water District",
          "link": "http://www.actonwater.com/",
          "href": "http://www.actonwater.com/"
        },
        {
          "title": "Contact Us — Acton Water District",
          "link": "http://www.actonwater.com/customer-service/contact-us",
          "href": "http://www.actonwater.com/customer-service/contact-us"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I'm trying to filter in each `url array` and remove any item that doesn't match the filter.

I've created a filter that successfully filters out the urls that dont contain the word "contact"

```
  const regex = new RegExp('/contact\\b', 'g');
  const companyColumn = db.get(`entities`).value()

  const filteredData = companyColumn.map((a ,i) => {
    return a.url.filter(({href}) => href.match(regex))
  })
```

and get the response:

```
[ [],
  [ { title: 'Contact Us — Acton Water District',
      link: 'http://www.actonwater.com/customer-service/contact-us',
      description: 'Office hours are Monday–Friday, 7:30 AM until 4:00 PM (excluding holidays) We \nare located at 693 Massachusetts Avenue, Acton, Ma 01720. Our mailing ...',
      href: 'http://www.actonwater.com/customer-service/contact-us' } ] ]
```

boom. so it works.

But my question is how can I set the first item in the "entities" array to have an empty `URL array`, while the second "entities" item has only 1 item in it's `URL array`.

I feel so close...

Comment: I'm a little unclear on what structure you want, but is `const filteredData = companyColumn.map(a => ({...a, url: a.url.filter(({href}) => href.match(regex))}))` what you're looking for?

Comment: Struggling to understand that last sentence, are you able to give an example output of what your after to save any confusion.

Comment: Use reduce rather than filter than it’s easier to manage the end result you want to achieve

Comment: If you want to *mutate* the original `companyColumn` then `companyColumn.forEach( a => {
    a.url = a.url.filter(({href}) => href.match(regex))
  })`